# Fonts won't work from different folder?

Tags: html, css

So I have a font folder and a css folder as a sibling, when I refer to the fonts it works only when the .html file is a sibling with the font folder, however it will use the styling css file correctly. Let me clear it up with this image: [image]

I'm refering to global_style.css from every index.html, and get correct styling in every index.html but the fonts will only work with the one which is not in any sub folders...

I have this in my root/subfolder1/index.html

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/global_style.css"/>
```

And this in every other index.html:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/global_style.css"/>
```

I suppose it should be working.

Here is my global_style.css:

```
@font-face{
font-family:"SourceSans";
src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro.otf');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"SourceSansIt";
    src: url('../fonts/SourceSansProIt.otf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"SourceSansB";
    src: url('../fonts/SourceSansProB.otf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"AllerBld";
    src: url('../fonts/Aller_Bd.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important; 
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-smooth: always;
    font-family:"SourceSans";
    font-size: 14px;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Relative paths in CSS are relative to the CSS file itself, not the html document that loaded the css. If your css is in `/foo/bar/styles.css`, then your fonts are going to be looked for in `/foo/fonts`.

Comment: but if you see the image you see that css folder and fonts folder are siblings so from the css file i have to acces the fonts like this ../fonts/font.ttf right?

Comment: You should use root selection- in this case `src: url('/fonts/SourceSansPro.otf');` should work

Comment: no it does not work @Vector

Comment: What browser are you using? http://caniuse.com/ttf and http://webfonts.info/node/379

Comment: I am using Firefox 25

Comment: The fonts are working on the main page, but not the sub pages... I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use absolute path to load the fonts:

```
@font-face{
font-family:"SourceSans";
src: url('http://www.yoursite.com/root/subfolder1/fonts/SourceSansPro.otf');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"SourceSansIt";
    src: url('http://www.yoursite.com/root/subfolder1/fonts/SourceSansProIt.otf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"SourceSansB";
    src: url('http://www.yoursite.com/root/subfolder1/fonts/SourceSansProB.otf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"AllerBld";
    src: url('http://www.yoursite.com/root/subfolder1/fonts/Aller_Bd.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important; 
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-smooth: always;
    font-family:"SourceSans";
    font-size: 14px;
    color:white;
}
```